# Failed to change my mac address by Android terminal Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, mac-address

I followed all steps in this article trying to change my mac address. https://geekeasier.com/change-mac-address-in-android-devices-without-root/4792/#comments.

Then when I entered `ip link set wlan0 address XX:XX:XX:YY:YY:YY` ,it shows `request send failed:permission denied`.

I was using mac address generator and didn't change the address prefix,I tried turn wifi on and off all still didn't work, don't know where do I go wrong.
Is the `wlan0` above should be something else?

Or there is something I have to do with phone first?

Comment: Which Android version and phone model? Also keep in mind the last paragraph of the article before the comments (it can work but does not have to and it may not work on newer Android versions).

Comment: Not working on Google Pixel with Pie update.

Comment: `ifconfig wlan0 hw ether xx:xx..` doesn't work either.